# CSS properties that support url

Tags: css

Id like to know all of the CSS properties that support url (both longhand and shorthand names), so far i can think of 3. I have searched the web, and haven't found a definitive list.

```
background: url(...);
background-image: url(...);
@font-face{ src: url(...); }
```

**edit (added from answers):**

```
list-style: url(...);
list-style-image: url(...);
content: url(...);
@import url(...);
cursor: url(...); 
play-during: url(...);
cue: url(...);
cue-after: url(...);
cue-before: url(...);
border-image: url(...);
border-image-source: url(...);
mask: url(...);
mask-image: url(...);
```

Is there any more?

Comment: [content: url(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: `cursor:  url(foo.cur), url(http://www.example.com/bar.gif), auto;`

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/indexlist.html#index-u see `<uri>`
border-image-source

Comment: `background` contains `background-image`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I'm interested in longhand and shorthand property names.

Comment: mask-image: url(...);

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

another one here

Comment: why -1 please?need to know